# Choose component loading order

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring boot with three `@Component` classes.

```
src.main.java
|_components
  |_A
  |_B
  |_C
```

I need `B` and `C` executed before `A` can be executed. How do I specify that?
Should I use `@DependsOn` annotation? Or `@Order`? All answers online are for `@Configuration` and `@Bean` classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use `@DependsOn` like this:

```
@DependsOn({"b", "c"})
@Component("a")
public class A {
}

@Component("b")
public class B {
}

@Component("c")
public class C {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Order(<int>)` notation when your components are advice and you want one advice to run before another advice.In that case the lower the number, the higher would be the precedence.
E.g.

```
Advice @Order(5) will have higher precedence over @Order(10).
```